# Been refused a Visa and an ESTA, when can I apply again?

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, esta

I'm arranging for some colleagues to travel to America, but one of them has just informed me that he was denied a Visa about 2 years ago, because the company that he was working for at the time put the 'wrong code' of travel use for him down, another company that he was working for applied for an ESTA for him in April 2018 and again he was denied this - because he had to declare that he was refused a Visa.

Can anyone answer for me - is it redundant for me to try and apply for him again, is the time scale too short?

Any help would be gladly received.

Comment: I think he is taking the visa process much to lightly. (Note: every refusal creates more difficulty to have visa in most of other countries). "Wrong code". I think he must check carefully the real reason (missing information). And not only read carefully the rejection letter, but also read carefully any new forms. [As I read it, to me it seems that he has no interest on traveling in US]

Comment: Are you asking about applying for a visa? or for an ESTA?

Comment: Are you getting the right facts? What `wrong code`? In any case you cannot arrange a visa for him. Visitors visas are applied for by the individual. You can help him with financial support and invitation however.

Answer (score 2):

There is no minimum time after a visa application for the filing of a subsequent application.  The likelihood of success, however, depends on the specific reason for the prior visa refusal.  See the State Department's page on [Visa Denials](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-denials.html).

On the subject of new applications, the page has this to say:

> Can I reapply for a visa?
>
> After being found ineligible for a visa, you may reapply in the future. If you reapply for a visa after being found ineligible, with the exception of 221(g) refusals, you must submit a new visa application and pay the visa application fee again. If you were found ineligible under section 214(b) of the INA, you should be able to present evidence of significant changes in circumstances since your last application. See more information below under INA section 214(b).

Note the lack of any limit on "in the future": it can be even one day in the future.

"Significant changes in circumstances" could include additional evidence to establish some circumstance that existed at the time of the first application but was not adequately reflected in that application.